# Retrieving a Model's morphOne object returns an Eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, polymorphic-associations

I have a Post model with a 
`public function image() { return $this->morphOne('App\Image', 'imageable'); }`

But when I tinker with `$post->image()` it returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne {#704}`

I have to add "->first()" to actually get the Image object. How do I have `$post->image()` return the Image object?

This is the relationship on the Image object: `public function imageable() { return $this->morphTo(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the *result* of the relationship, you should call the dynamic property `$post->image`, rather than the method `$post->image()`.

The [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) documentation explains through basic relationship usage, though it is easy to read past if you're skimming. I'd suggest taking your time and reading most, if not all of this page as you begin to work with relationships.

Comment: Thanks - was stuck in mindset of `____ to many` relationships.

Comment: The syntax is the same regardless of relationship type. It just depends on if you want to modify a relationship before retrieving the results (e.g., add `where` conditions), or just getting the results of a relationship directly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, I need to use `$post->image` to get the related Image object. Silly me. I think my confusion stems from being stuck in the mindset of many to many or one to many relationships.